# Pass value by reference to the holder object

Tags: go

Following code has Holder specified as of `interface` type.

What changes can be done to the Holder object so it receives any kind with reference type, so if any changes to the value object, it gets reflected on the main.

```
type Holder struct {
    Body interface{}
}

type Value struct {
    Input int
    Result int
}

func main() {
    value := Value{Input: 5}
    holder := Holder{Body: value}

    fmt.Println(value) // {5 0}
    modify(holder)
    fmt.Println(value) // {5 0} should display {5 10}
}

func modify(holder Holder) {
    var value Value = holder.Body.(Value)
    value.Result = 2 * value.Input
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MndJLdVDaL)

Comment: Stop thinking about "references" (there are none in Go) and the solution becomes obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Holder struct {
    Body interface{}
}

type Value struct {
    Input  int
    Result int
}

func main() {
    value := Value{Input: 5}
    holder := Holder{Body: &value}

    fmt.Println(value) // {5 0}
    modify(&holder)
    fmt.Println(value) // {5 0} should display {5 10}
}

func modify(holder *Holder) {
    var value *Value = holder.Body.(*Value)
    value.Result = 2 * value.Input
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hG8cH4UBPc

Comment: Some explanation beyond raw source code might be beneficial to a broader audience than the OP. Good answer though.